# Android: Crash on app versionCode greater than 1

Tags: android

I'm running Android Studio 3.3.2 creating a simple app for Android 9.0.  The app runs correctly on the emulator, Nexus 5X API 27.  My Samsung J7 test phone is API 27, too.

When I run on the phone with the versionCode 1 (the default in the gradle build at the module level) the app runs well on the phone. If I change the versionCode to 33, however, the app crashes on run (and keeps crashing). I un-install the app before loading a new version.

The versionCode and versionName of the apk on the phone are what they should be and the manifest looks good on the phone via "Apk Analyzer".

Comment: can you please post your crash log?

Comment: From Android Studio you run `debug build` but from Google Play you download `release build`.  There may be configuration mistake in `build.gradle`

Comment: App runs correctly from Android Studio in debug mode.

Comment: Got adb logcat running and crashed the app.  There's a lot of stuff!  What do I look for?

Comment: Download from Play Store works successfully on Samsung Tablet at 4..4.2 and an LG phone at 4.1.2.  Very strange that an Android Studio run to the Samsung J7 phone works, but the generated APK bundle, when transferred doesn't work. Is this a problem with different APK loaders?

Comment: The release signature file had a 3rd party verification that had expired. The debug version sent to the emulator is apparently unsigned and didn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too but the app stopped crashing after updating/increasing the `versionName` in `build.gradle`.